# Aggregate by field and then extract the min of other field (like Group By & Having)

Tags: elasticsearch

I have this docs inside my elastic db:

```
{
  ProcessInstanceId: aaaa-bbbb-cccc-dddd
  StartDateTime: 2016-09-27 08:00
  EndDateTime: 2016-09-27 08:01
}

{
  ProcessInstanceId: aaaa-bbbb-cccc-dddd
  StartDateTime: 2016-09-27 08:01
  EndDateTime: 2016-09-27 08:02
}


{
  ProcessInstanceId: aaaa-bbbb-cccc-dddd
  StartDateTime: 2016-09-27 08:02
  EndDateTime: 2016-09-27 08:03
}

{
  ProcessInstanceId: aaaa-bbbb-cccc-dddd
  StartDateTime: 2016-09-27 08:03
  EndDateTime: 2016-09-27 08:04
}
```

My goal is to get an output of:

```
{
  ProcessInstanceId: aaaa-bbbb-cccc-dddd
  MinStartDateTime: 2016-09-27 08:00
  MaxEndDateTime: 2016-09-27 08:04
}
```

Is this possible ?

I've tried to use aggregation.. but I'm not sure that's the right way to go:

```
GET /monitor*/_search
{
  "query": {
    "term": {
      "ProcessName": "SomeProcessName"
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "ProcessIDAgg": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "ProcessID.raw"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "MinAgg": {
          "min": {
            "field": "StartDateTime"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're on the right path, you simply to add one more `max` metric aggregation for the `EndDateTime` field:

```
POST /monitor*/_search
{
  "query": {
    "term": {
      "ProcessName": "SomeProcessName"
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "ProcessIDAgg": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "ProcessID.raw"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "MinStartDateTime": {
          "min": {
            "field": "StartDateTime"
          }
        },
        "MaxEndDateTime": {
          "max": {
            "field": "EndDateTime"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```